# Xamarin.Forms - Build Errors when trying to deploy to local iOS Device - "The given path's format is not supported"

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

## The Issue

I have a Xamarin.Forms app, which runs fine in Android and iOS Simulators, as well as on a physical Android device.

But when I try to deploy to a local physical iOS device, Visual Studio reports a number of similar build errors, all relating to files that I have in the `wwwroot` folder.

For example:

> Unable to copy file "..\BlazorHybridApp\wwwroot\weather.json" to "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\BlazorHybridApp.iOS.app\out\Payload\BlazorHybridApp.iOS.app\D:\Dev\MobileBlazorBindings\BlazorHybridApp\BlazorHybridApp\wwwroot\weather.json". The given path's format is not supported.    BlazorHybridApp.iOS

Similarly:

> Unable to copy file "..\BlazorHybridApp\wwwroot\css\app.css" to "C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\Temp\Xamarin\HotRestart\Signing\BlazorHybridApp.iOS.app\out\Payload\BlazorHybridApp.iOS.app\D:\Dev\MobileBlazorBindings\BlazorHybridApp\BlazorHybridApp\wwwroot\css\app.css". The given path's format is not supported.  BlazorHybridApp.iOS

Looking at the error detail, the destination path does appear to be malformed.

Interestingly, some of the files included in the build errors are not in fact referenced anywhere within the program code as it stands (e.g. the `weather.json` file), and so I'm led to believe it's not a referencing/path issue within the program code itself.  It seems sufficient for a file to appear in the `wwwroot` folder (or one of it's sub-folders) for it to generate a build error, but ONLY when building for a physical iOS device.

## The Environment

### Mac

I'm including the Mac details for completeness, but it seems the build doesn't get as far as the Mac before stopping with build errors.

- Xcode 12.5

### Windows

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019 version 16.10.4

I have disabled "Hot Restart" in `Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings` in case it was messing things up.

[image]

And the files within the `wwwroot` folder are set as follows within VS:

[image]

**Can anyone suggest anything I might try?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to "resolve" the issue myself, well, at least side-step it.

When I was getting the build errors, I was trying to deploy to a physical device connected to my Windows machine.

If instead I connected the device to the Mac, and ran the same build process on Windows, the build completed with no errors.

Another weird quirk of Visual Studio, it would seem.